# Type of date as prompt

Tags: sas, prompt

I have standard routine for PROMPT_DATA: can be type month('January 2024') or type=day ('24jan2024')

```
  DATA_ = INPUT("&Prompt_DATA.", ANYDTDTE.);
  %LET HasComma = %SYSFUNC(INDEXC(&Prompt_DATA_LABEL., ','));
  %IF &HasComma. > 0 %THEN %DO;
```

I'm looking for a ',' so i know it means day.
How can i better test the type of Prompt_Data?

Comment: Why are you mixing data step language and macro language?

Comment: What method are you using to generate the PROMPT_DATA and PROMPT_DATA_LABEL?  Are you using Enterprise Guide? SAS/Studio? Something else?

Comment: Sorry i am using Enterprse Guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a fine approach, just no reason to mix the macro language with the data step language.

```
DATA_ = INPUT("&Prompt_DATA.", ANYDTDTE.);
IF (INDEXC("&Prompt_DATA_LABEL.", ',')) THEN DO;
 

END;
```

Beyond that, SAS doesn't have types really here - just numeric and character.  If it accepted a "month" type, it likely would be assigned the 1st of the month (so "January 2024" -> `01JAN2024`), but you can't just test for that - the first of the month is after all a legal value for the day version as well.